# Как изменить надпись количества отзывов woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

как изменить данную надпись, на (3 reviews ) без слова customer. Заранее благодарю за ответ.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Найти файл темы

wp-content/themes/ваша_тема/woocommerce/single-product/rating.php

Если его нет, то скопировать его из плагина

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/rating.php -> wp-content/themes/ваша_тема/woocommerce/single-product/rating.php

Найти в нем фрагмент

```
<a href="#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<?php printf( _n( '%s customer review', '%s customer reviews', $review_count, 'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' ); ?>)</a>
```

заменить на

```
<a href="#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<?php printf( _n( '%s review', '%s reviews', $review_count, 'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' ); ?>)</a>
```

Comment: "ваш_шаблон".. Не шаблон же... А тема!

Comment: @SeVlad изменил. но думаю это синонимы и не сильно принципиально, если тему назвать шаблоном

Comment: Ну ты даёшь.. Вроде и ВП не плохо разбираешься, а такие основы путать.. Это принципиально разные понятия. См https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F